# Parsing JSON in nodejs with api.call

Tags: json, node.js

I'm trying to parse a JSON response from an API that i'm using. I don't have direct access to the file and I can stringify the response but I can't parse the JSON at all, Ideally I want the value of "display_name" in a variable.

Here's what I have:

```
var api = require('twitch-irc-api');

api.call({
    channel: null,
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/channels/greatbritishbg/follows',
    options: {
        limit: 1,
        offset: 0
    }
}, function(err, statusCode, response) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
    console.log('Status code: ' + statusCode);
    console.log('Response from Twitch API:');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
    console.log(JSON.parse(response);
});
```

stringify response:

> Response from Twitch API:
>   {"follows":[{"created_at":"2015-06-02T06:11:10Z","_links":{"self":"https://api.t
>   witch.tv/kraken/users/feddecampo/follows/channels/greatbritishbg"},"notification
>   s":false,"user":{"_id":50947595,"name":"feddecampo","created_at":"2013-11-01T17:
>   22:49Z","updated_at":"2015-05-30T19:50:21Z","_links":{"self":"https://api.twitch
>   .tv/kraken/users/feddecampo"},"display_name":"FeddeCampo","logo":"http://static-
>   cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/feddecampo-profile_image-d4f7de23b28e0a86-300x30
>   0.jpeg","bio":"Playstation MVP Sony and PS fan ","type":"user"}}],"_total":2315,
>   "_links":{"self":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/greatbritishbg/follows?d
>   irection=DESC&limit=1&offset=0","next":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/gr
>   eatbritishbg/follows?direction=DESC&limit=1&offset=1"}}

Comment: Try `console.log(response.follows[0].user.display_name);`

Comment: "*...but I can't parse the JSON at all*" - what happens when you use `JSON.parse`? Can you at least provide an example of the data structure coming back to prevent people having to go look at the API documentation...

Answer (score 0):

The `response` is already 'parsed'

If you format the output, it becomes easier to read:

```
{  
   "follows":[  
      {  
         "created_at":"2015-06-02T06:11:10Z",
         "_links":{  
            "self":"https://api.t witch.tv/kraken/users/feddecampo/follows/channels/greatbritishbg"
         },
         "notification s":false,
         "user":{  
            "_id":50947595,
            "name":"feddecampo",
            "created_at":"2013-11-01T17: 22:49Z",
            "updated_at":"2015-05-30T19:50:21Z",
            "_links":{  
               "self":"https://api.twitch .tv/kraken/users/feddecampo"
            },
            "display_name":"FeddeCampo",
            "logo":"http://static- cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/feddecampo-profile_image-d4f7de23b28e0a86-300x30 0.jpeg",
            "bio":"Playstation MVP Sony and PS fan ",
            "type":"user"
         }
      }
   ],
   "_total":2315,
   "_links":{  
      "self":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/greatbritishbg/follows?d irection=DESC&limit=1&offset=0",
      "next":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/gr eatbritishbg/follows?direction=DESC&limit=1&offset=1"
   }
}
```

You can get at the properties in the normal js way:

```
var displayName = response.follows[0].user.display_name
```

Comment: Is there anyway to make this a string and call it in another function?

Comment: make it a string? why? and what do you mean by call it in another function?

Comment: I need to return the output in nodejs like so: `client.say(channel, 'user.display_name ' + user.username + '!');` Which is in a different function.

Comment: that makes even less sense! you're already "in nodejs" - can you provide some more context? you can just do exactly what you've put: `nt.say(channel, 'user.display_name ' + response.follows[0].user.display_name + '!');`

Comment: Alex, I'm doing it within another function inside that .js file. The other function: `client.addListener('chat', function (channel, user, message) { I NEED IT HERE });`

Comment: you really need to read up on callbacks, and how to use them, this is out of scope for this question.